# session values are disappearing in heroku

Tags: php, session

In my project i am using the session in all the page.Actually i am setting the value in the index file like

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userId']=$userid;
```

Here i am assigning the value and i am checking all the page if userid is there or not.
And redirection is happening from index file.There also i started session like `session_start()`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){

}
```

Problem is some time it is going to the loop and sometime not.
And i am not setting any time or sleep or destroy or unset ..nothing.

**Note:** This problem is not happening in localhost.

Please help.

Comment: Make sure every page has the `session_start()` function, not only at the page where you set the session.

Comment: yes In all the page i started the session using session_start()

Comment: What error(s) do you get after turning on the `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: am not getting any error using this function